# Wrong URL showing up in Google search results resulting in 404 error after migrating from blogger to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url, google, search

I have ported a blogger blog to a WordPress blog.  I have switched the DNS to point to the new WordPress blog. The WordPress blog is up and running fine. I have created sitemaps for the pages on this blog and have added them to Google Webmaster Tools.

Now when I take the title of any blog post and enter the words from it into Google:

```
understanding getting past cognitive limitations decisions makers
```

Google returns the incorrect URL to me in the search results:

```
/2016/03/understanding-and-getting-past.html
```

Instead of

```
/2016/03/understanding-getting-past-cognitive-limitations-decisions-makers/
```

I'm getting so many 404 errors because of such bad URLs.  This happens with every URL in the site map, even though in the site map has the correct, fully formed URLs.

What is going on here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Google isn't going to forget about the URLs that your blog used when it was hosted on Blogger.   When you switched to WordPress each blog post got a new URL.   Now when somebody tries to visit the page on its old URL, they get a 404 error.

To fix this you need to implement "301 Permanent" redirects between each old URL and its corresponding new URL.

Without the redirects,Google will eventually pull all these 404 pages from its index.   That will be good in so far as the 404 errors will stop, but Google may not always replace the page with its new URL.   The new URLs will eventually get indexed, but they won't rank as well.

Even if Google does pull the old URLs from the search index, it will still have Googlebot come visit them.

Without the redirects, any inbound links other than to the home page will also be broken.   The redirects are important for any visitors that come to your site through deep links as well.

[Here is a guide](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-switch-from-blogger-to-wordpress-without-losing-google-rankings/) for migrating from Blogger to WordPress.   It has an entire section on setting up the redirects including code that can be pasted into `functions.php` in WordPress that will handle the redirects.

Comment: There are other ways to handle the redirects too, such as [implementing a redirect map](http://searchengineland.com/create-301-redirect-map-203248), but that article looks like it covers your specific site move perfectly.